# Single word for someone who "leads people on"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for a person who won't speak up when they don't want to do something, or who makes excuses about doing something without actually coming out and saying they dont want to?

Comment: passive-aggressive

Answer (score 2):

Equivocator. It means "to use ambiguous or unclear expressions to avoid commitment, or to mislead" ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/equivocator)).

Answer (score 1):

I think you could describe this person as  [unassertive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unassertive):

> - not talking or behaving in a loud and confident way : not assertive (M-W)

If you want a term with a stronger connotation you can use [servile](http://www.yourdictionary.com/servile):

> - someone who is submissive and who is extremely willing to act to please others.

Answer (score 0):

Passive?

From merriam webster:
adjective: passive
1. 
accepting or allowing what happens or what others do, without active response or resistance.

"the women were portrayed as passive victims"

synonyms: submissive, acquiescent, unresisting, yielding, unassertive, non-resistant, compliant, complaisant, pliant, resigned, obedient, docile, tractable, malleable, pliable, meek, subdued, deferential, forbearing, long-suffering, patient, lamblike, non-violent, supine